# Application crash when delete invoked

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char* p=new char[10];
p="sudheer";
char* q=new char[10];
q=p;
delete []p;

return 0;
}
```

When I run the above program, it crashes with delete. Any comments?

Comment: Pro tip: use `std::string` instead.

Comment: A tutorial on pointers will surely help you. Take a look at any of the recommended C++ books

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are deleting a string literal "sudheer", that's enough to crash a program.

I think your error is not understanding how to copy a C string, use `strcpy` for that. Also if you use `new []`, you must use `delete[]` not `delete` . You probably meant to write this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* p=new char[10];
    strcpy(p,"sudheer"); // use strcpy to copy C strings
    char* q=new char[10];
    q=p;
    delete[] p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But it didnt crash with `p="sudheer"`. As I have mentioned it was crashed with `delete []p;`.

Comment: @user2820017 `p="sudheer";` is not an error, deleting `p` after doing `p="sudheer";` is an error. `p` is just a pointer, it points to memory. When you do `delete[] p;` it must be pointing at dynamically allocated memory. When you wrote `p="sudheer";` you made `p` point to a string literal, not to dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

the literal constant `"sudheer"` is understood as a pointer to a 8 bytes read-only memory zone.

You are deleting it, this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The previous result of `p=new char[10]` is a non-reachable memory zone. You have a memory leak.

I suggest using `std::string` so declare

```
std::string p = "sudheer";
```

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a pointer to characters. First, you create 10 character memory block and tell `p` to point to that (`p=new char[10];`). The next line you tell `p` to instead point to another memory block with the text "sudheer" in it (`p="sudheer";`).

At this point `p` no longer points to the memory block you allocated so deleting `p` doesn't deallocate that block. It tries to deallocate the string.

Indeed - *nothing* points to the 10 character memory block anymore. It is lost inside the memory of the computer. This is a memory leak.

Notice you are doing the same with `q`. If you want to *copy* strings use `strcpy`. Or, obviously, you could use `std::string` (with `#include <string>`) and then have strings that act like you expect them to act instead of pointers use in c.

Answer (score 0):

```
p="sudheer";
```

and then

```
delete p;
```

It fails as you overrun dynamically allocated `p` and then trying to delete it.